# How to add container to a selected list items dynamically using javascript or jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-ui, dynamic

I have a code like this:-

> ```
> <div id="one">Some HTML code</div>
> <div id="two">Some HTML code</div>
> <div id="three">Some HTML code</div>
> <div id="four">Some HTML code</div>
> <div id="five">Some HTML code</div>
> ```

As you can see every div container has a different id. So what I want to create from above is this dynamically

> ```
> <div id="something">
>     <div id="one">Some HTML code</div>
>     <div id="two">Some HTML code</div>
>     <div id="three">Some HTML code</div>
> </div>
> <div id="four">Some HTML code</div>
> <div id="five">Some HTML code</div>
> ```

I want to create it using JavaScript or Jquery. So can anybody help.

Thanks

Comment: Have you tried anything so far? What is the surrounding tags?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the wrapAll function to do this.

```
$("#one, #two, #three").wrapAll('<div id="something">')
```

For more information, refer http://api.jquery.com/wrapAll/